# avoiding duplicate file with blueimp File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload, struts2

How can I avoid adding duplicated file in blueimp jquery file upload? 
I've tried this solution:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function(e,data) {

    var currentfiles = [];
    $(this).fileupload('option').filesContainer.children().each(function(){
        currentfiles.push($(this).data('data').files[0].name);
    });

    data.files = $.map(data.files, function(file,i){
        if ($.inArray(file.name,currentfiles) >= 0) { 
            alert("il file "+file.name+" è già presente nell'elenco.");
            return null; 
        }
        return file;
    });
    $('.fileupload-loading').hide();

});
```

but this give me an error when I try to add new files after a previous upload.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this one. It worked for me.

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function(e,data) {

    var currentfiles = [];
    $(this).fileupload('option').filesContainer.children().each(function(){
        currentfiles.push($.trim($('.name', this).text()));
    });

    data.files = $.map(data.files, function(file,i){
        if ($.inArray(file.name,currentfiles) >= 0) { 
            alert("il file "+file.name+" è già presente nell'elenco.");
            return null; 
        }
        return file;
    });
    $('.fileupload-loading').hide();

});
```